# Setting UITableViewController Delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I have a class of type UITableViewController and I am going to add the required delegate methods to that class am I right in thinking I don't need to specify a delegate as the class defaults to using itself?

Comment: i'm not 100% on this without checking, but i think if you are subclassing the UITableViewController the [super init] sets delegate as self. So yes you maybe right.

Comment: Thats what I thought, I usually set this up using InterfaceBuilder and sometimes it sets things like this for you. This time I have done it programatically and just wanted to check I was understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure it is a good idea to make a class be its own delegate. Maybe it would work with UITableViewController, but I read that this wouldn't work with UITextField for example, because it intoduces a message loop, see: [Problem with TextField set as its own delegate](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/282093-uitextview-as-its-own-delegate-infinite-loop-on-keyboard-select.html)

However, whether you decide on trying or specifying another delegate, you need to adopt the UITableViewControllerDelegate protocol in any case.

Comment: I think he was talking about setting the delegate of the tableView to the TableViewController. UITableViewController does not have a delegate property anyway.